# Inakzeptabel oder unakzeptabel?

Tags: meaning

Gibt es beide Versionen um etwas zu beschreiben was *nicht* akzeptabel ist?
Beide Versionen stehen im Duden [[1]](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/inakzeptabel)[[2]](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/unakzeptabel).

Comment: Wenn beide Wörter in (prominenten) Wörterbüchern auftauchen, was lässt dich daran zweifeln, dass sie auch beide verwendet werden können? *Hinweis:* Eine deiner Quellen führt aus, dass "*-in*" die lateinische Variante des deutschen "*-un*" ist, also beide Wörter gleichbedeutend sind.

Comment: Mich würde daran zweifeln lassen, dass ich das Wort "unakzeptabel" noch nie gehört habe. Daher gebe ich +1 für die Frage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beide Versionen sind möglich und korrekt.

**In**akzeptabel ist m. E. geläufiger und klingt auch konsistenter, da es sich bei *akzeptabel* ja bereits um ein Lehnwort handelt und die lateinische Vorsilbe daher besser passt als die deutsche.

Comment: +1 **Un**akzeptable habe ich schon lange nicht mehr gehört, und hätte ich im ersten Moment auch für falsch gehalten. Sprachraum: Hamburg

Comment: Ich stimme bei der Geläufigkeit zu, die Erklärung halte ich aber für dürftig. Es gibt durchaus auch viele lateinische Lehnworte, die mit _un-_ negiert werden. Die [Antwort von tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44359/inakzeptabel-oder-unakzeptabel/61245#61245) überzeugt da mehr.

Answer (score 6):

Es gibt beide Versionen. Die Bildungsform "negiertes Lehnwort" kann man sprachgeschichtlich so verstehen, dass das Lehnwort entweder in seiner nicht negierten Form ins Deutsche übernommen und erst nach seiner Einführung mit dem deutschen "un-" negiert wurde, oder schon direkt in der Ursprungssprache negiert von dort übernommen wurde.

Im Allgemeinen gibt es beide Formen, in unterschiedlicher Gebräuchlichkeit. Je verankerter das Lehnwort in der deutschen Sprache ist (d.h., je mehr es als "deutsches Wort" wahrgenommen wird), umso akzeptabler und gebräuchlicher ist auch die deutsche Negierung mit "un-", wenn beide Formen existieren. "Un-" *kann* deshalb als "falsch" wahrgenommen werden, mit der ursprungssprachlichen Negierung liegt man i.A. immer richtig.

Comment: Die Erklärung ist gut, aber der letzte Satz scheint mir etwas vorschnell verallgemeinert zu sein. Siehe etwa praktisch alle aus dem Latein entlehnten Adjektive, die bereits in der nichtnegierten Form mit _in-_ beginnen: _uninformiert_,  _uninspiriert_, _unintelligent_. Aber auch sehr viele andere Beispiele, die mir nur so einfallen: _unproduktiv_, _unkorreliert_, _unzensiert_. Auch wenn sich über die Erkennbarkeit der Entlehnung im Einzelfall sicherlich diskutieren lässt, habe ich nicht das Gefühl, dass sie hier das Hauptkriterium ist, sondern dass andere Konventionen hier den Ausschlag geben.

Comment: Im Grunde widerspricht diese im letzten Satz genannte Faustregel ja auch genau der überzeugenden Analyse am Anfang - dass sprachgeschichtlich entscheidend ist, ob das negierte Wort entlehnt wurde, oder das entlehnte Wort negiert.

Comment: Hier muss man ein bißchen genauer kucken: "produktiv" ist ein aus dem Französischen, nicht aus dem Lateinischen übernommenes Wort - deswegen wäre "inproduktiv" keine "Negation in der Ursprungssprache". Zu "informiert", "intelligent", "inspiriert" - mit der Vorsilbe "in" beginnende Wörter werden auch im Lateinischen nicht mit "in" negiert - deshalb wäre "ininformiert" einfach falsch. Natürlich ist die Faustregel etwas grob - das haben Faustregeln so an sich. Und sie geht davon aus, daß auch beide Formen im Duden stehen.

Answer (score 1):

Ergänzend zu tofro hier noch ein paar Beispiele zu dem Wortbildungsmuster "un*abel":

> unkomfortabel, unprofitabel, unpraktikabel, undiskutabel, unvariabel, unrentabel

Mit dem komplementären Muster "in/m/r*abel" finden sich (außer *inakzeptabel*)

> indiskutabel, inoperabel, intolerabel, inkommensurabel (?), invariabel, impraktikabel, irreparabel

Nur bei *diskutabel* und *variabel* käme demnach auch die Vorsilbe *in-* in Frage. Die Adjektive mit *in-/im-/ir-* wirken deutlich fremwortartiger.

Es gibt etliche weitere auf *-abel*, die jedoch mit *un-/in-* meist ungebräuchlich sind:

- *blamabel, miserabel, passabel, portabel, spendabel, transportabel*.

Teilweise besteht dort kein Bedarf, diese Adjektive negativ zu verwenden (?nicht blamabel), oder es existieren Antonyme (spendabel >< knauserig). Bildungen mit *un-/in-* kommen jedoch vor.

Außer den genannten häufigeren gibt es eine Reihe weiterer bildungssprachlicher, selten gebrauchter Adjektive, denen man die fremde Herkunft noch stärker ansieht und anhört. Diese werden eher mit *nicht* negiert:

- favorabel, formidabel, habitabel, justitiabel ...

---

Man könnte die Überlegung ausweiten auf *-ibel*:

> inkompatibel, inflexibel, irreversibel

Hier kann man alternativ auch "unflexibel" sagen, die anderen sind mit un- ungebräuchlich. Alle lassen sich in eine Phrase mit dem Muster "lässt sich nicht/schlecht ...' überführen, denn zu allen dreien lassen sich auch Synonyme mit -bar bilden:

> unvereinbar, un-/schlecht biegbar, unumkehrbar.

Mit "un*ibel" gibt es

> unflexibel, unsensibel, unplausibel

Allgemein ist es oft stilistisch besser, das Basisadjektiv mit *nicht* zu verwenden.

Answer (score -7):

Warum sollte man unsinnig das lateinische IN, anstatt das Deutsch UN verwenden.

Wenn man sich die Synonyme für unakzeptabel anschaut, die alle mit dem deutschen UN anfangen, dann wird klar, dass das deutsch UN verwendet werden sollte:

uneinlösbar, unvertretbar, übertrieben, unmöglich, unbrauchbar, untauglich, untragbar, unvernünftig, unannehmbar, ungünstig, unerträglich, ungeeignet.
https://www.synonyme.de/inakzeptabel/

Comment: Das ist eine meinungsbasierte Antwort. Die Beispiele, die du bringst, entsprechen nicht der gleichen Bildungsregel ("negiertes Lehnwort"). Passende Beispiele wären "intolerant", "inkompetent", ...

Comment: Weil akzeptabel ein aus dem Lateinischen entlehntes Wort ist?

Comment: vgl. auch _intransparent_, _indiskutabel_, _indefinit_, _inkommensurabel_, _indisponiert_ usw. usf. Die Antwort ist nicht nur (unnötig) normativ und dabei rein meinungsbasiert, sondern gibt auch den tatsächlich anzutreffenden Sprachgebrauch falsch wider. Daher gebe ich hier -1.